# Inkscape: radial opacity gradients on jpgs

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create an image where I'd like to include part of a jpg image in the following way: I'd like to have the "outer" part of the jpg at the fringes, so that it is opaque on the edges and transparent in the middle (where the main part of my image is). I've tried the following:
1. Adding a radial opacity gradient to the jpg itself as if it were a vector-based object.
2. Creating an Inkscape object with an analagous gradient and then doing a Clip>Set with the jpg.

Neither of these worked (obviously). Is there a way to do this in Inkscape? all of my attempts have either done nothing, or have only succeeded in changing the opacity of the image uniformly (without a gradient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you want is called Masking, you can find it right below Clip in the menu in Inkscape.

The darker or more transparent the mask object is, the more it hides from what is below. So you need a gradient that goes from black in the center to white at the outer perimeter.

The rest works just like clipping.